# Prove $(a,b]$ is closed in the Upper Limit Topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Recall that in the set of all real numbers, if $\Sigma$ is all sets of the form $\{ x \vert x > a\}$ and $\{ x \vert x \leq b\}$, then $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$ is called the Upper Limit Topology and has the sets $(a,b]$ as basis.

Therefore, $(a,b]$ are obviously open sets in $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$, and I need to show that they are also closed in $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)$ (clopen!)

Could someone please tell me if my proof of this below is correct, and/or what I can do to polish it up and make it nicer? Thank you in advance.

> Consider $(a,b]^{c} = (-\infty,a] \cup (b, \infty)$.
>
> Now, $\displaystyle (-\infty, a] = \cup_{-n < a} (-n,a]$ so $(-\infty,a]$ can be expressed as the union of basis elements in $\mathcal{T}$, and thus is open.
>
> Also, $\displaystyle \cup_{n=b+1}^{\infty}(b,n] = (b,\infty)$, so we have written $(b,\infty)$ as the union of basis elements of $\mathcal{T}$. Therefore, $(b,\infty)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$.
>
> Since we have shown $(-\infty,a]$ and $(b,\infty)$ to be open, $(-\infty,a] \cup (b,\infty)$ is open, so $(a,b]^{c}$ is open.
>
> Therefore, since $(a,b]^{c}$ is open, $\left((a,b]^{c}\right)^{c} = (a,b]$ is closed.

Please note that this is not homework. I am studying for my midterm, trying to predict possible test questions, and making sure I am able to do them sufficiently well.

Comment: This proof is correct

Comment: Note that the elements from $\Sigma$ are already clopen, one type is the complement of the other type so their both clopen. The finite intersection of clopen sets is clopen; hence your base is too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x: x > a\}$ and $\{x: x > a\}^c = \{x: x \le a\}$ are both in $\Sigma$, so $\{x: x >a\}$ is clopen. Same for $\{x: x \le b\}$. As your subbasic elements are clopen,your base elements, which are finite intersections of clopen sets, are also clopen.